# Update Survey Template across Web Application

Tags: 2013, list-template

I have a very specific requirement and need to know the path forward in SharePoint 2013

1. I need to disable the Survey template (available in Site Contents) across the Web Application.
2. Than, i need to create a my own survey template with "Show User Names" option set to No and make sure no one change it in list settings.

Any reference material or steps would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deactivate feature "Team Collaboration Lists" list feature from web level

1) After that you can not get OOTB survey list in Sharepoint.

NOTE : You can not get announcements and links longer if you will do  deactivate above feature.

Customization :
You can create new content type with your required fields and bind it to with your custom list.